# Diffing two time stamps under selection

Tags: vimscript

Is there a way to make a function in vim that takes the difference between two time stamps under highlight?

For example:

```
1 20:37:00 
2 20:42:30
```

Supposing you highlight lines `1` and `2` and run the command, say, `:TimeDifference`, you get the output `5.5` (i.e., `5.5` minutes) which replaces lines `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
" line1 is the line number the first timestamp is on.
" line2 is the line number the second timestamp is on.
function! GetTimeDifference(line1,line2)
    " Get line content and split it where ":" matches.
    let l:t1List = split( getline(a:line1), ":" )
    let l:t2List = split( getline(a:line2), ":" )

    " Get the difference in minutes between the timestamps.
    let l:difference = abs(  (l:t1List[0] * 3600 + l:t1List[1] * 60 + l:t1List[2]) - 
                           \ (l:t2List[0] * 3600 + l:t2List[1] * 60 + l:t2List[2])   ) / 60.0

    " Replace the line with the result.
   call setline(a:line1, printf("%.1f" ,l:difference))

    " Delete the other one.
    execute a:line2 . "delete"
endfunction

" Create a user-defined command.
command! -range TimeDifference :call GetTimeDifference(<line1>,<line2>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function.

Select two lines, then :TimeDifference 
it'll generate the third.**

```
03:42:53
08:13:18
4 hrs 30 min 25 sec
```

Inspired from @Jair López code

```
"" line1 is the line number the first timestamp is on.
" line2 is the line number the second timestamp is on.
function! GetTimeDifference(line1,line2)
    " Get line content and split it where ":" matches.
    let l:t1List = split( getline(a:line1), ":" )
    let l:t2List = split( getline(a:line2), ":" )

    " Get the difference in seconds
    let l:diffSec = abs(  (l:t1List[0] * 3600 + l:t1List[1] * 60 + l:t1List[2]) - 
                           \ (l:t2List[0] * 3600 + l:t2List[1] * 60 + l:t2List[2])   ) 
    let l:sec=trunc(fmod(l:diffSec,60))
    let l:min=trunc(fmod(l:diffSec,3600) / 60) " 60x60
    let l:hrs=trunc(l:diffSec / 3600)

    " Replace the line with the result.
   call append(a:line2, printf("%.0f hrs %.0f min %.0f sec", l:hrs,l:min,l:sec))

    " Delete the other one.
    " execute a:line2 . "delete"
endfunction

" Create a user-defined command.
command! -range TimeDifference :call GetTimeDifference(<line1>,<line2>)
```

**TODO**: make it work with a.m. / p.m.